# How to improve top end of vocal range?

Tags: voice

I'm a baritone and I can't get the word "me" in Photograph by Ed Sheeran without cracking.

Comment: how does it work with *moon*, *noon*, *soon*, *ten*, *teen*, *when*, *mean*?

Comment: 'Sometimes a man has to know his limitations'. Clint Eastwood. There are few reasons why anyone else should be able to reach a certain note.

Comment: Which "me"? Is it just that one song's note, or is this a problem in every song? More details, please.

Answer (score 1):

How many times have you sung it? If the answer is more than 50, over more than 6 weeks, allowing sensible breaks, then give up now; otherwise keep going.

If you can reach it, but it's a strain, then one of two things will happen over time.
You will either eventually be able to do it… or you won't.

Don't try it with a cold voice, warm up on something else first so you don't bust a gut in the first 5 minutes.

If you over-do it, trying 10 times in a row on your first day, you'll hurt something, perhaps permanently.

Take breaks.
Allow a day or two between practise sessions.
You may feel an improvement over a few days, then it gets worse - if so, then leave it alone for a week & come back to it.
Sing something else instead, but keep practising.
Practising never means over-pushing anything. It means gentle improvement over time.

Eventually you will either strengthen your voice sufficiently to hit the note clean, or you will discover it's never going to happen.

It will take 6 weeks or so to become certain of either of those conclusions.

Personally, I have a rough list of songs in ascending order of difficulty.
I do this if I've not been singing for a while & need to test how quickly I can get back into the swing of it.
Start with the easiest, see how that one goes.
Up to a harder one… rinse & repeat.
If at any point you are starting to fail or struggle, give up for the day & come back tomorrow.

It's a bit like running. You don't do a marathon on day one.

It may turn out that the troublesome note is right on your break-point. You might be able to do the song either a tone down, or even a tone up.
Practise & training will never totally eliminate your break point, but it can strengthen the 'join' so you can sail through it more easily & get more power to it if you need to, for short periods.

Answer (score 0):

First : *don't* force it.

Do you have a teacher?

You might be able to extend your vocal range by regular practice, but there is generally a limit.

Do you mean in " wait for me come home"? it happens at several places, and on different notes. It would help if you posted a link to the song and a time reference for where you have the problem.

It doesn't seem to be the highest note in the song, so it is probably to do with the vowel sound and where it sits on your vocal break. But it is pretty hard to say what the problem is without more info.